# Neo4j REST multiple statements request with same query & different paramerters

Tags: rest, neo4j, parameter-passing, cypher

I use Neo4j Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint.

http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/http-api/#rest-api-execute-multiple-statements

I need to do a request with multiple statements where cypher query is the same for all statements, but parameters is different:

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "MATCH path=shortestPath( 
(p:Person {idp:123})-[*..10]-(p2:Person {idp:{idp2}}) ) 
RETURN reduce(x={
        last_idp: +head(nodes(path)).idp,
        str:""    +head(nodes(path)).idp },
    r IN relationships(path)  |
    {
        last_idp: CASE WHEN x.last_idp = startnode(r).idp THEN endnode(r).idp ELSE startnode(r).idp END,
        str: CASE WHEN x.last_idp = startnode(r).idp 
            THEN x.str +"-" +type(r)+"->"+ endnode(r).idp
            ELSE x.str +"<-"+type(r)+"-" + startnode(r).idp 
             END
    }
).str AS rpath",

    "parameters" : {"idp2": 1234}
  }, {
    "statement" : "<the same chypher query as above>",
    "parameters" : {"idp2": 1234}
  }, {
    "statement" : "<the same chypher query as above>",
    "parameters" : {"idp2": 1235}
  },
  ...
  {
    "statement" : "<the same chypher query as above>",
    "parameters" : {"idp2": 1255}
  } ]
}
```

How can I simplify the request to avoid pointless repetition of the cypher query string?

And I would like to avoid unnecessary costs to parsing & planning the same query.
Is it possible?

Comment: If it's exactly the same query, it won't be parsed or planned again: the Cypher engine caches those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass all the `idp2` parameter values in a single collection, and add an `UNWIND`clause to the top of your Cypher query. That will cause the query to be executed for each `idp2` value.

For example:

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" :
      "UNWIND {idp2s} AS idp2
      MATCH path=shortestPath((p:Person {idp:123})-[*..10]-(p2:Person {idp:idp2})) 
      RETURN reduce(
        x={
          last_idp: +head(nodes(path)).idp,
          str:""    +head(nodes(path)).idp },
        r IN relationships(path)  |
        {
          last_idp: CASE WHEN x.last_idp = startnode(r).idp THEN endnode(r).idp ELSE startnode(r).idp END,
          str: CASE WHEN x.last_idp = startnode(r).idp 
            THEN x.str +"-" +type(r)+"->"+ endnode(r).idp
            ELSE x.str +"<-"+type(r)+"-" + startnode(r).idp 
            END
        }
      ).str AS rpath",

    "parameters" : {"idp2s": [1234,1235,1236,1255]}
  }]
}
```